# States: Liouvilleans

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with dynamics $\tau$.

Consider an invariant state: $\omega\circ\tau^t\equiv\omega$

Then the dynamics is unitarily implementable:
$$\pi_\omega\left[\tau^t(A)\right]=e^{itL}\pi_\omega[A]e^{-itL}$$

Moreover the Liouvillean is determined by: $L\Omega=0$

I'm wondering what other generators can occur: $L\Omega\neq0$

Does somebody have an explicit example on Fock space?